# Extract video from sony handycame with perfect quality

Tags: video, encoding, camcorder, tape, usb

I've got an old sony handycame that record into tapes. When i try to display the videos in my samsung tv using RCA cables, the video is full screen and with a really good quality.

I wanted to transfer the videos into my computer using usb communication. I've got the handycam's driver, installed, the handycam is recognized as well.

Using OpenCV library, have been able to collect the pictures but in a resolution of 320*240, resolution of the screen of my handycam.

When i try to resize the pictures, the quality get really bad. I would like to have videos of more than default resolution, with a good quality.

So, how come that the videos are displayed so well into the tv, but not in my computer ? and is there any way to solve this problem ?

CAMCORDER: DCR-TRV238E
TV: SAMSUNG PS43D450A2W

Comment: How does that camera save video that it shoots? If it's DV tape you'll need a firewire connection most likely. If you can hunt down a manual on the internet or IRL that will help.

Comment: I think a firewire will be usefull since the camera chip doesn't encode the data before transfering them, just my computer doesn't have a firewire entry , is there any other suggestion please ? sorry for late answer